# C program- how do I integrate 2 strings into eachother?

Tags: c

I know its a confusing title, but basically I have string1 that is "Hello" and string2 that is "there"

I need to create a third string that has them mixed like: **H**t**e**h**l**e**l**r**o**e (bolded so you can see it better).

I am new to C, and to be honest I'm not even quite sure how to start to go about this. I know there should definitely be a for loop that maybe has something like string1[i-1] != '\0'  in the middle. Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us some effort and we'll be happy to help you along - but your question is almost a "do my homework for me" type of question, which only get's people upset.

Comment: hint: `newstring[2*i]` and `newstring[(2*i)+1]`

Comment: What will the output be if the inputs are "Hello" and "goodbye"?

Comment: http://ideone.com/RmuyVc

Comment: Firstly, try to explain the process to do what you want in natural language.

Answer (score 1):

We beginners should help each other.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how this can be done

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char *s1 = "Hello";
    char *s2 = "there";
    char s3[strlen( s1 ) + strlen( s2 ) + 1];

    char *p1 = s1, *p2 = s2, *p3 = s3;
    int first = 0;

    while ( *p1 && *p2 )
    {
        *p3++ = ( first ^= 1 ) ? *p1++ : *p2++; 
    }

    while ( *p1 ) *p3++ = *p1++;
    while ( *p2 ) *p3++ = *p2++;

    *p3 = '\0';

    puts( s1 );
    puts( s2 );
    puts( s3 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
there
Htehlelroe
```

These three statements

```
while ( *p1 ) *p3++ = *p1++;
while ( *p2 ) *p3++ = *p2++;

*p3 = '\0';
```

can be substituted for

```
while ( *p1 ) *p3++ = *p1++;
while ( *p3++ = *p2++ );
```

If the compiler does not support variable length arrays then you need to allocate array s3 dynamically using malloc.

For example

```
char *s3 = malloc( strlen( s1 ) + strlen( s2 ) + 1 );
```

If the first two strings are "Hello" and "goodbye" then the output will be

```
Hello
goodbye
Hgeololdobye
```

You can also use the approach shown in the post of **@Pedro Rodrigues** . For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char *s1 = "Hello";
    char *s2 = "there";
    char s3[strlen( s1 ) + strlen( s2 ) + 1];

    char *p1 = s1, *p2 = s2, *p3 = s3;

    do
    {
        if ( *p1 ) *p3++ = *p1++;
        if ( *p2 ) *p3++ = *p2++;
    } while ( *p1 || *p2 );

    *p3 = '\0';                    

    puts( s1 );
    puts( s2 );
    puts( s3 );

    return 0;
}
```

It is the same program as shown by **@Pedro Rodrigues** but it does not use indices.

Comment: Thanks! It's helpful to see it done with pointers, as I really wasn't sure how it would be done with them, as I just learned them.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much effort you've put into solving this problem, but here goes a possible way of solving it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Give me two strings!");
        return 1;
    }

    int len = strlen(argv[1]) + strlen(argv[2]);
    char mixed_string[len];
    char *a = argv[1];
    char *b = argv[2];
    int i ;
    for(i = 0; i < len;)
    {
        if(*a)
        {
            mixed_string[i++] = *a++;
        }

        if(*b)
        {
            mixed_string[i++] = *b++;
        }
    }

    mixed_string[i] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", mixed_string);

    return 0;
}
```

Now a little explanation. The new string's size will be the size of both strings:

```
int total = strlen(argv[1]) + strlen(argv[2]);
char mixed_string[total];
```

We alternate characters between one string and another while the smallest string still has characters to read:

```
for(i = 0; i < total;)
{
    if(*a)
    {
        mixed[i++] = *a++;
    }

    if(*b)
    {
        mixed[i++] = *b++;
    }
}
```

I don't really need to check which one is smaller, that is implicit when I'm checking if the pointers are pointing to something valid.

You can run this on the command line by passing two strings as input (I'm using Bash and GCC here):

```
➜ ~/Code/C gcc -o test test.c
➜ ~/Code/C ./test First Second
FSiercsotnd
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, @VladfromMoscow :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    char c1[]="Hello",c2[]="There",c3[11];
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    while(c1[i]!='\0' && c2[j]!='\0')
    {
            c3[k]=c1[i];
            k++;
            c3[k]=c2[j];
            k++;
            if(c1[i]!='\0')
                    i++;
            if(c2[j]!='\0')
                    j++;

    }
    c3[k]='\0';
    printf("%s\n",c3);
```

}

Try this, it'll Work

Comment: Thanks! It's helpful to see the pointers used in the other answers, along with just the arrays.